# SARIMAX with series without time as index, or how to make row sequential index as time index?

Tags: pandas, time-series, prediction, statsmodels, arima

I have a pandas series `ts` of numbers that I want to predict for its future (next 600 points). The pandas series is just indexed by sequence number, not by date nor time.

Here is the example content of `ts`:

```
    0           1
0   -0.801552   1.0
1   -0.997606   2.0
2   -3.659062   3.0
3   -1.193043   4.0
4   -2.858001   5.0
```

When I ran

```
statsmodels.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX
```

with the series, I got the following exception error:

```
ValueError('Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates',)
```

But according to SARIMAX's documentation, for the first argument:

```
endog : array_like

The observed time-series process y
```

It seems that it only expects the argument to be array_like.

How can I make the series work with SARIMAX and the eventual ARIMA model without date and time as the index?

I'm thinking if I could fake the row index as minutes or seconds from the start of time?  How?

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the series into a numpy array.

```
newts = ts.values
```

Another method that worked for me was similar to what you implied with replacing the index with timestamp.

```
ts.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
```

[Here's the documentation for the date_range function.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) To help you generate the exact timestamps your series requires.